# Change in y axis label alignment when rotating x axis text in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

So, I've noticed when I rotate the text for the x-axis in my plots, the positioning of the y axis label relative to the graph changes a lot.  It appears that it's centered position relative to the entire frame is maintained, even though the graph itself has been compressed into the upper portion of the plot.  This makes it look odd.  So, in this example

```
data(diamonds)
diamonds$cut <- paste("Super Dee-Duper",as.character(diamonds$cut))
q <- qplot(cut,carat,data=diamonds,geom="boxplot")
q + opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=-90))
```

[image]

The label carat is scrunched down between the 1 and 2.  It's odd.  Is there anyway to stop this behavior?  Or fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this has been fixed in the dev version of ggplot2. You can get it from github or use devtools to install it. You could always turn the label off `+ labs(y="")` alltogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, it's fixed in the development version of ggplot2 which, if I'm not mistaken is to be released in Mar:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("ggplot2")

data(diamonds)
diamonds$cut <- paste("Super Dee-Duper",as.character(diamonds$cut))
q <- qplot(cut,carat,data=diamonds,geom="boxplot")
q + opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=-90))
```

[image]

Comment: And it looks like the axis.text is a little smaller in the dev version too. In case you want it bigger + `opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(size=X), axis.text.y=theme_text(size=X))`